# jQuery autocomplete select first data when click outside ?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using Jquery + JS + rails4

```
    function get_city_names(div_name, div_id, cities){
  div_name = "#" + div_name;
  div_id = "#" + div_id;
     $(div_name).autocomplete({
        autoFocus: true,
        maxLength: 5,
        source:  function(request, response) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" +   $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep(cities, function( item ){
              return matcher.test(item.name);
          }) );
      },
      // Focus - if you mouse over any item the input field replace by that value
        // focus: function( event, ui ) {
        //   console.log(ui.item.name);
        //   $(div_name).val( ui.item.name );
        //   return false;
        // },
        // Select - If you  select any item it'll give the values (ID) and label
        select: function(event, ui) {
          $(div_name).val(ui.item.name); // Label display
          $(div_id).val(ui.item.id); // Assign ID with respect city.
          return false;
        },
        // close: function(event, ui) {
        //   $(div_name).autocomplete('close');
        // },
      }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      console.log(ul[0]);
        return $("<li>")
          .append( "<a>" + item.name + "</a>" )
          .appendTo(ul);
      };
}
```

autocomplete is working fine but i want when i will click outside then it should take automatically first one from the list.

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

use [focus out](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_focusout.asp) event and check this extension of [select first](http://dev.nemikor.com/jquery-ui-extensions/autocomplete/selectFirst.html). Hope it helps..